# JAXB and matching property names

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, code-generation

I am trying to use the XJC utility to generate classes from an XSD file. It works OK except when looking into my generated class i get:

```
* You are getting this "catch-all" property because of the following reason: 
* The field name "Products" is used by two different parts of a schema. See: 
* LINE 16 of FILENAME.xsd
* line 15 of FILENAME.xsd
```

Looking at the xml:

*EDIT* - adding namespace definitions

```
...
xmlns:def="http://www.host.com/DEFResponse" 
xmlns:abc="http://www.host.com/ABCResponse"
...
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.host.com/ABCResponse" schemaLocation="ABCXMLResponse.xsd"/>
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.host.com/DEFResponse" schemaLocation="DEFXMLResponse.xsd"/>
...
<xsd:choice minOccurs="0">
    <xsd:element name="HostResponse" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element ref="abc:Products"/>
    <xsd:element ref="def:Products"/>
</xsd:choice>
```

How using bindings can I tell it to make two properties, one called ABCProducts and one called DEFProducts?

My attempt below is not-working:

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="FILENAME.xsd">
    <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:choice">
        <jaxb:bindings node=".//xs:attribute[@ref='abc:Products']">
           <jaxb:property name="ABCProducts"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:bindings node=".//xs:attribute[@ref='def:Products']">
            <jaxb:property name="DEFProducts"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: you should use a binding file to specify class names for these colliding elements. Also, do you have specified namespaces in the xsds?

Comment: I've referenced what I attempted to do with a bindings file in the last code block. The namespaces are defined: xmlns:def="http://www.host.com/DEFResponse" 
            xmlns:abc="http://www.host.com/ABCResponse"

Comment: But do you have targetNamespace in the abc and def schemas? If they have different namespaces, then they shouldn't clash

Comment: Yes, both of the additional included response XSD's have targetNamespace, example:  <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.host.com/ABCResponse"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns="http://www.host.com/ABCResponse" 
            elementFormDefault="qualified"
            attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="2.609">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the bindings xml also needed:

```
xmlns:def="http://www.host.com/DEFResponse" 
xmlns:abc="http://www.host.com/ABCResponse"
```

to be defined for the selections to work.

```
<jaxb:bindings node=".//xs:attribute[@ref='abc:Products']">
       <jaxb:property name="ABCProducts"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node=".//xs:attribute[@ref='def:Products']">
        <jaxb:property name="DEFProducts"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsd:element ref="abc:Products"/>
<xsd:element ref="def:Products"/>
```

`abc:Products` and `def:Products` are two xsd elements, and in your xsd you defined `xsd:` prefix not `xs:` ... so change binding file as below.

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="FILENAME.xsd">
    <jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:choice">
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:element[@ref='abc:Products']">
           <jaxb:property name="ABCProducts"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:element[@ref='def:Products']">
            <jaxb:property name="DEFProducts"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```